# Why are there parentheses around (int) in this example?

Tags: c, syntax, parentheses

```
decimal d = 2;
int i = (int) d;
```

I've seen this several times in which parentheses are wrapped around data types.

Why not just use `int i = int d;`?

Comment: This is the syntax for [type casting](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm).

Comment: it is a cast of the variable `d`, which is defined as a `decimal` to a type of `int` in order to allow the assignment of `d` to `i` to not generate a compiler warning.  Usually it is not a good practice and can lead to mysterious bugs.

Comment: We don't know what `decimal` is, but we do know that you can initialize a `decimal` with the value `2`. Given that information, the cast is unnecessary; `int i = d;` would perform the conversion implicitly. It might make sense to make it explicit if the cast is non-trivial. What is `decimal`?

Answer (score 6):

The usage of `(int)` is called `cast`ing (or, [type-casting](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm)). It is essentially telling that, <del>*interpret*</del> *convert* the value of `d` <del>*as*</del> to an `int` (integer) and store it into `i`.

In other words, it is a way of converting a *type* to another one (subject to validity of the conversion).

BTW, `int i = int d;`, as is, is not a valid statement.

Comment: What did I miss? I mean, reason for downvote, anyone?

Comment: NMDV, but perhaps "interpret" may not be as good as "convert".

Comment: @chux Thank you for your comment sir. I intentionally used _interpret_ as I did not want anybody to get the misconception that somehow `d`'s value is getting affected. I always have trouble expressing my thoughts in prefect English. Do you suggest I should change that to _convert_ ?

Comment: Do not recommend changing an answer based on an anonymous down-voter whose intention is not clearly understood.   I suggested "convert" as that matches the C spec: "... result from a cast operation (an _explicit_ conversion)." C11 6.3 1

Comment: @chux Absolutely sir, you're very right. We should abide by the standard and standard only. I was not worrying about the downvoter, anyway, I was bothered about making the answer correct. As per your suggestion, I'll change it to `convert`, as that is what backed by the standard. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're casting d to type int from type decimal. This happens in other languages as well that use static typing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a way of converting data type from one type to another using cast operator, usage is as follows:

- (result data type) expression to be converted