# Type in parentheses in C variable definition

Tags: c, variables, types, declaration, definition

I came across some syntax in C that I am unfamiliar with. After declaring a variable, `long ja`, the variable was then assigned to using `ja=(long)(3.14)`.

```
long ja;
ja=(long)(3.14);
```

What is the significance of having `(long)`, or `(`*variable type*`)` in the assignment to a variable that has already been declared?

Comment: It's a [cast](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm) from one type to another.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570, `6. Language 6.5 Expressions 6.5.4 Cast operators`. I suspect there's a lot of the language you are not familiar with. This part is not exactly obscure.

Comment: `long ja;` both declares and defines the variable.

Comment: It's a bad way of writing `ja = 3;` or `ja = 3L;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C, why are there parentheses around (int) in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790649/in-c-why-are-there-parentheses-around-int-in-this-example)

Answer (score 7):

This line is an assignment, not a declaration:

```
ja=(long)(3.14);
```

It takes `3.14`, which is a constant of type `double`, casts it to `long` (resulting in the value `3`), and assigns that value to `ja`.

Answer (score 3):

The value *3.14* is a `literal float`, and *ja* is a `long`
Attempting to assign the floating value to a `long` *[lvalue](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c)* would result in a compiler warning, such as:

> warning: implicit conversion turns literal floating-point number into
>   integer:double to long.

To facilitate the assignment properly, and to suppress the warning, the syntax

```
ja=(long)(3.14)
```

is said to ***[typecast](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson11.html)*** `3.14` to `long`.
Typecasting is a way to make a variable of one type, such as a float, act like another type, such as a long, for one single operation.